# Invert Z-axis in Matrix4::Perspective

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I'm making an OpenGL application in which I have the following code to setup the perspective matrix.

```
Matrix4 Matrix4::Perspective(float pL, float pR, float pB, float pT, float pN, float pF) {
    Matrix4 matrix;
    matrix[0] = 2 * pN / (pR - pL);
    matrix[5] = 2 * pN / (pT - pB);
    matrix[8] = (pR + pL) / (pR - pL);
    matrix[9] = (pT + pB) / (pT - pB);
    matrix[10] = -(pF + pN) / (pF - pN);
    matrix[11] = -1;
    matrix[14] = -(2 * pF * pN) / (pF - pN);
    matrix[15] = 0;
    return matrix;
}
```

As it stands when I manipulate the translation of the object, -Z moves it forward, +Z moves it backwards.

I came close to obtaining this behavior by switching matrix[11] and matrix[14] to:

```
matrix[11] = 1;
matrix[14] = (2 * pF * pN) / (pN - pF);
```

But the mesh becomes slightly deformed. (Probably hugely deformed on a more complex mesh.)

How would I manipulate this method to give me the desired result (invert z axis)?

pF = zFar
pN = zNear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, what you want invert *z* before the projection is applied, which will have the effect of mirroring the projection from -z to z. So what you conceptually have to do is calculating `P * Scale(1,1,-1) = P * diag(1,1,-1,1)`. If you do the math, you will see that this just results in negating the third *column* of the projection matrix, so the correct matrix will be:

```
matrix[0] = 2 * pN / (pR - pL);
matrix[5] = 2 * pN / (pT - pB);
matrix[8] = -(pR + pL) / (pR - pL);
matrix[9] = -(pT + pB) / (pT - pB);
matrix[10] = (pF + pN) / (pF - pN);
matrix[11] = 1;
matrix[14] = -(2 * pF * pN) / (pF - pN);
matrix[15] = 0;
```

Negating `matrix[14]` like you did doesn't make the slightest sense, it just will move your near and far planes to elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply... I'll have to crack open the old linear algebra textbooks to try and understand the transformation better. Will accept the answer in a moment but I still have a slight problem, the mesh is being "collapsed" and just rendering slightly off... I'll get a screenshot. Screenshot: http://oi66.tinypic.com/ojfd5s.jpg  (Let me know if you need one of the original before the z-axis flip, or if you want a picture with wireframe off.)

Comment: Sorry, I had just forgotten to invert the z-axis when importing the mesh! Do I have to invert the normals as well?

Comment: I don't know, since I have no idea what you are doing, or why you even need to flip the z in object space again.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I'm rendering a 3d mesh in OpenGL, to fix the issue shown in the screenshot I needed to change the following: `mesh.HasPositions() ? Vector3(mesh.mVertices[i].x, mesh.mVertices[i].y, 1.0f - mesh.mVertices[i].z) : Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),` This code is ran when generating an "internal model format" from assimp. That works! it all works! :) thanks. I just had to flip the position vertices in the model, However, I was wondering if I have to flip the normals as well. I.E: `mesh.HasNormals() ? Vector3(mesh.mNormals[i].x, mesh.mNormals[i].y, 1.0f - mesh.mNormals[i].z)`

Comment: Well, if you flip the vertex coords, you also have to flip the normals. However, your code doesn't just flip the coords (that's the `-` in there), it also translates them (that's the `1.0f` there). You must not apply a translation to direction vectors, but you must still flip the normals, so `Vector3(mesh.mNormals[i].x, mesh.mNormals[i].y, - mesh.mNormals[i].z)`.

Comment: Oops never even noticed I was doing that. Thank you once again!